# Highcharts chart title and subtitle overlapping on Iphone 5

Tags: iphone, mobile, highcharts, title, subtitle

I am using [Highcharts](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts). How do I control the chart Title and Subtitle so it looks good on desktop, ipad and iphone? Now the Title and Subtitle are overlapping (see image) on iphone 5 (and 6). I want some bottom margin on the Title.

[image]

Comment: Do you have live example of your chart?

Comment: https://www.staatvenz.nl/kerncijfers/aanvullend-verzekerden-zorgverzekering

Comment: I would say the problem is an issue of responsiveness in general, and not anything to do with iPhone - the title is too long for the narrow screen, and so wraps and overlaps. Not aware of a specific option that will fix, but you could look at detecting screen size, and adjusting your parameters (or the title itself), for narrow screens.

Comment: ok thanks. But within the Highcharts js settings, is it possible to target the screen size and make adjustments in the settings regarding responsiveness?

Answer (score 0):

You can play around with the marginTop property for the chart itself, or the x/y properties for the title or subtitle objects.

```
chart: {
   type: 'line',
   marginTop: 100
}
subtitle: {
   text: 'Your text',
   y: 100
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/chart/margintop/

Demo2: http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/title/y/

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But then I get problems on Iphone, Ipad. It's not consistent? Is there a solution for this?